# Change background image of Navigation Bar buttons

Tags: ios5

I'm trying to change the background image of the Navigation Bar buttons for all the app. I guess it has to be done in the appDelegate.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target is iOS 5, you can put this code in your AppDelegate:

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (version >= 5.0)
{
    // iPhone 5.0 code here
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image.png"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the appearance proxy for that. Just add this in your appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barButtonItemBackground.png"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setBackgroundImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    return YES;
}
```

For more detail check the session 114 of the WWDC 2011